# Calculate $f(4)$ if $\int_{0}^{f(x)} s^{2}ds=x\sin(\pi x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let be f a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$

1. Calculate $f(4)$ if $\int_{0}^{x^{2}}f(s)ds=x\sin(\pi x) \ \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
2. Calculate $f(4)$ if $\int_{0}^{f(x)}s^{2}ds=x\sin(\pi x) \ \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

*My approach:*

**1.** Note that $\frac{d\left ( x sen(\pi x) \right )}{dx}=\pi x \cos(\pi x)+ \sin(\pi x)$

By the other side, we have that: $\frac{d\left ( \int_{0}^{x^{2}}f(s)ds \right )}{dx}=f(x^{2})\cdot 2x$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt{x}+\pi \sqrt{x}cos)(\pi \sqrt{x})}{2 \sqrt{x}}\\ \\
\Rightarrow f(4)=\frac{sin(2 \pi)+2 \pi \cos(2 \pi)}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

**2. I have doubts in this exercise, what I have done is this:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\left ( x sen(\pi x) \right )}{dx}=\pi x \cos(\pi x)+ \sin(\pi x)\\ \\
\frac{d\left ( \int_{0}^{f(x)}s^{2}ds \right )}{dx}=f^{2}(x)\cdot f'(x)\\ \\
f^{2}(x)\cdot f'(x)=\pi x \cos(\pi x)+ \sin(\pi x)
\end{align*}

The goal is to calculate f(4), but *I'm not sure how to continue*. Can you help me? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_0^{f(x)}s^2ds=\frac13s^3\Big\vert_0^{f(x)}=\frac13(f(x))^3$$

Answer (score 2):

**2. Calculate $f(4)$ if $\int_{0}^{f(x)}s^{2}ds=x\sin(\pi x) \ \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$**

The right hand side, when $x=4$ is $4\sin 4\pi=0$.  Since $s^2$ is non-negative and positive for $s>0$, $f(4)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{3}(f(x))^3=xsin(\pi x)$$
$$f(x)=(3xsin(\pi x))^\frac13$$

Answer (score 1):

**1. Calculate $f(4)$ if $\int_{0}^{x^{2}}f(s)ds=x\sin(\pi x) \ \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$**

Let $F(x)$ be such that $F^\prime(x)=f(x).$

$F(x^2) -F(0)=x \sin\pi x$

$\displaystyle \frac{dF(x^2)}{dx}=2 x f(x^2) = \pi x\cos \pi x+\sin \pi x$

$f(x^2) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cos \pi x + \frac{1}{2x} \sin \pi x $

$f(x) =  \frac{\pi}{2} \cos \pi \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \sin \pi \sqrt{x}$